# Managing data for matchmaking server

Tags: c#

I am creating multiplayer game (nothing serious, just experimenting), i have ran into a "problem", i have  to store 3 value - userid, zone and type.

I have two options for storing them: userid, tuple< zone, type >

```
public Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>> BigDictonary = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>>();
```

or: userid, type

```
public Dictionary<int, int> Zone1 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
public Dictionary<int, int> Zone2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

My zones are predetermined and they don't change over the run of the game

Which approach should i use, one big dictonary or few small one ?

Comment: How do you use this information in your application? What does the combination of these three values represent? Once it is in the dictionary how do you intend to use it?

Comment: Maybe you can create a small class (object) that holds the 3 values? This way it is easy to add values in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered making a class for storing this data?

```
public class Zone {
     // UserID as key, type as value.
     public Dictionary<int, int> Users { get; set; }

     public Zone {
          Users = new Dictionary<int, int>();
     }

     public void AddUser(int userID, int typeID)
          Users.Add(userID, typeID);
     }
}
```

Then using it to create two zones, and add the users and types to them:

```
Zone1 = new Zone();
Zone2 = new Zone();

Zone1.AddUser(1, 0);
```

Comment: With the information provided by OP at this time, any permutation of the three values as a "root" represented by a class would be possible, i.e. why not a class "User" with properties "Zone" and "Type"?

Comment: @Alex, that would be possible, I'm a bit confused on what OP is trying to do.

Comment: I didn't consider that actually, thanks for bringing it up. Will definitely use it.